# How to convert string into json object with JOLT transformation

Tags: json, jolt

is it possible if I have json format in string to desereialize it in json object, using JOLT transformation?

Input:

```json
{
  "Id": 1,
  "Name": "{\"NameId\":1,\"LastNameId\":1000}"
}
```

Output:

```json
{
  "Id": 1,
  "Name": [{"NameId":1,"LastNameId":1000}]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below jolt spec to get the desired output

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "&",
      "N*": {
        "*:*,*:*}": {
          "$(0,2)": "&2[#2].&2Id",
          "$(0,4)": "&2[#2].Last&2Id"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { // get rid of quotes for integer values
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "*": "=toInteger"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```